# How to inherit right from parent prototype JS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

The question - how to get the right methods inheriting from parent (Animal) to child (Rabbit) prototypes that will does not override the parent prototype props after creating an object, based on child prototype. I mean, the creating object (rabbit) must gets prototype method (.prototype.walk) from Rabbit prototype, not from parent (Animal).

I know that we can make easy solution and move the method this.walk behind the  constructor Animal and create prototype method Animal.prototype.walk... But I wonder if we can do this without pushing this.walk out of constructor brackets? Is that some JS trik?

I'll be grateful for the any answer, thanks!

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;

  this.walk = function() {
    console.log( "walk " + this.name );
  };

}

// Animal.prototype.walk = function() {   //// we can not use this trik and 
//    console.log( "walk " + this.name ); //// delete this.walk function in 
//}                                       //// constructor


function Rabbit(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments);
}

Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;

Rabbit.prototype.walk = function() {
  console.log( "jump " + this.name );
};

var rabbit = new Rabbit("Rabbit");
rabbit.walk(); // for now we get "walk Rabbit". But need - "jump Rabbit"
```

Comment: "*we can not use this trik*" - why not? You *should* do exactly that.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I know, but is there any other way? The snag is that a couple of times I met a parent prototypes with such inheritance and in practice we were not allowed to take the methods from the constructor, to make from they a prototypes.

Comment: "*in practice we were not allowed to take the methods from the constructor*" - I think you need to work on that problem, not search for better workarounds than the obvious one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You are mixing two different ways of defining methods in JavaScript. You should pick one way of doing it and stick with it.

---

With `Animal` you are defining the `walk` method within the body of the constructor. This will create a new function each time the constructor is called. It's easy to read, but will waste memory as *every* instance will have its own identical `walk` method.

With `Rabbit` you are taking advantage of the Rabbit's `prototype`, so that each instance instead shares a single `walk` function. You can think of prototypes in JS as backup objects. JS first looks for a property on the instance itself. If not found, it will work it's way up the "prototype chain" until it finds the property or runs out of prototypes.

For example, with your code, if I called `rabbit.toString()`, I would end up traveling up the chain something like this:

```
rabbit.toString           --> undefined
Rabbit.prototype.toString --> undefined
Animal.prototype.toString --> undefined
Object.prototype.toString --> ƒ toString() { [native code] }
```

However, when you call `rabbit.walk()` it never makes it even to the first prototype, because `Animal.apply(this, arguments)` added a `walk` function directly onto the `rabbit` instance.

The way to fix this is to define your two `walk` methods either *both* on a prototype (preferable) or *both* in the constructor body.

---

Alternatively, you could take advantage of ES6 syntax, which will put your `walk` method on the prototypes in the background, but looks a lot cleaner than doing it manually:

```
class Animal {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  walk () {
    console.log(`walk ${this.name}`)
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  walk () {
    console.log(`jump ${this.name}`)
  }
}

const rabbit = new Rabbit('Rabbit')
rabbit.walk()  // "jump Rabbit"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `Animal` constructor defines a `.walk` function on every instance, to overwrite them the `Rabbit` constructor must do the same:

```
function Rabbit(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments); // creates an own .walk property

  // overwrites the own .walk property
  this.walk = function() {
    console.log( "jump " + this.name );
  };
}
```

You can also share the function object for better memory usage:

```
function rabbitWalkMethod() {
  console.log( "jump " + this.name );
}
function Rabbit(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments);
  this.walk = rabbitWalkMethod;
}
```

(you can also use the `Rabbit.prototype.walk` property to store it instead of the local variable `rabbitWalkMethod`, but that's probably confusing to any readers who will assume that the method is getting inherited)

Comment: Great! But, in this way we need to move the child prototype method .prototype.walk to Rabbit constructor (like this.walk). Can we make the solution that will hold parent .walk method in the parent constructor and Rabbit.prototype.walk method like prototype of child?